# Why is my Project Euler problem 25 answer wrong?

Tags: python

Project Euler question 25 https://projecteuler.net/problem=25, pretty simple. The problem to solve is:

> What is the index of the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?

but my answer is wrong, I cannot figure out why.

It couldn't be simpler, I just got the wrong answer

```
def fib_gen(i=1, j=1):


  yield 1

  yield 1

  while 1:

    i, j = i+j, i
    yield i

for i, f in enumerate(fib_gen()):

  if f < (10**1000):
    pass
  else:
    if f > (10**1000-1):
      print(i+1, f)
      break
```

my answer 4787

the right answer 4782, I think.

> UPDATE never mind. I figured out 10**1000 is 1001 digits number

Comment: You should use maths instead of brute force. Remember Euler loved logarithms, see if you can use them to find an expression for the number of digits in the *n*th term.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem that it's a 1001 digit number? Python supports numbers that large.

Comment: @Barmar I am looking for the first 1000-digit number. My code got a the first 1001-digit one.

Answer (score 0):

You would get 4782 if you used `if f > (10**(1000-1)):`.

Comment: You should explain why it makes a difference.

Comment: @PeterWood Why is it a bad question? Other than linking to Project Euler instead of copying the specification here, it seems fine. It has the MCVE, expected result, and incorrect result.

Comment: @PeterWood It's not even indented wrongly, a problem that afflicts at least 75% of python questions.

Comment: @Barmar It links offsite, refers to the Euler question number rather than actual problem they're having, isn't the simplest example (what about trying for the 10th or 100th term?), it is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: @PeterWood Since the bug is in how he's expressing the term number, he wouldn't have a problem if he were just trying for the 10th or 100th term. And I already mentioned the offsite link. It's not a perfect question, but not so horrible that it should be deleted rather than improved.

Comment: @PeterWood I've added the Euler problem description. It specifically asks for the term with at least 1000 digits, not the 10th or 100th term.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
def fib(limit):
    var, var1,l = 0,1,0
    for i in range(limit):
        ph = var1
        var1, var = var+var1, ph
        l = ph
    return l

counter = -1
while 1:
    counter += 1
    v = fib(counter)
    if len(str(v)) == 1000:
        print(counter)
        break
# output: 4782
```